# Boost Subgraph Implementation and exporting using Graphml

Tags: c++, boost, qt-creator

I am using boost 1.53.0, I have implemented a small demo using boost for subgraph.
I need to export the subgraph information in the graphml file, while exporting it will create all the nodes in the parent graph but not able to hold the information about it's subraphs.
so please help me if there is any way to hold information about subgraph?.
My implementation is exporting as follows:

```
enter code here

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns 
http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">

<graph id="G" edgedefault="undirected" parse.nodeids="free" 
parse.edgeids="canonical" parse.order="nodesfirst">

<node id="n0">

</node>

<node id="n1">

    </node>

<node id="n2">

</node>

<node id="n3">

</node>

<node id="n4">

</node>

<node id="n5">

</node>

<edge id="e0" source="n0" target="n1">

</edge>

<edge id="e1" source="n1" target="n2">

</edge>

<edge id="e2" source="n1" target="n3">

</edge>

<edge id="e3" source="n4" target="n1">

</edge>

<edge id="e4" source="n4" target="n5">

</edge>

<edge id="e5" source="n5" target="n3">    

</edge>    

<edge id="e6" source="n2" target="n5">    

</edge>    

</graph>    

 </graphml>
```

Actully the nodes n0,n1,n2 are members of subgraph G1 and n4,n5 are members of subgrph G2.
G0 is main parent graph.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the way to deal with above problem. This problem is solved by combining the use of dynamic properties from boost and also using bundled properties from boost.
this code works for boost 1_53_0.
Reference property map is used for storing the properties of boost subgraph.

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <boost/graph/subgraph.hpp>
#include <QMap>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
enum graph_IDproperty_t
{
    graph_IDproperty
};
namespace boost
{
    BOOST_INSTALL_PROPERTY(graph,IDproperty);
}
struct GraphProperties {
   std::string strName;
   std::string id;
};
typedef boost::subgraph<boost::adjacency_list< boost::listS,
boost::vecS,
boost::bidirectionalS,
boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int , property<boost::vertex_color_t,         boost::default_color_type > > ,
boost::property<boost::edge_index_t,int, property<boost::edge_color_t ,  default_color_type> > ,
boost::property<graph_IDproperty_t,GraphProperties > > >
Graph;
Graph gMainGraph;
typedef QMap<Graph*,GraphProperties*> mapGraphToProperty;
mapGraphToProperty getMap(Graph& graph);
void graphMapRecur(mapGraphToProperty& map, Graph& graph);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

Graph& subG = gMainGraph.create_subgraph();
Graph& subG1 = gMainGraph.create_subgraph();

boost::ref_property_map<Graph*, GraphProperties>
        graph_propt1(boost::get_property(subG1,graph_IDproperty));

graph_propt1[&subG1].id = "SubG1";
cout<<graph_propt1[&subG1].id<<endl;

boost::ref_property_map<Graph*, GraphProperties>
        graph_propt(boost::get_property(subG,graph_IDproperty));

graph_propt[&subG].id = "SubG";
cout<<graph_propt[&subG].id<<endl;

boost::ref_property_map<Graph*, GraphProperties>
        graph_proptMain(boost::get_property(gMainGraph,graph_IDproperty));

graph_proptMain[&gMainGraph].id = "gMain";
cout<<graph_proptMain[&gMainGraph].id<<endl;
mapGraphToProperty map = getMap(gMainGraph);

boost::ref_property_map<Graph*, GraphProperties>
        graph_proptMain1(*(map.value(&gMainGraph)));

boost::ref_property_map<Graph*, GraphProperties>
        graph_proptsubG(*(map.value(&subG)));

boost::ref_property_map<Graph*, GraphProperties>
        graph_proptsubG1(*(map.value(&subG1)));

cout<<"Main G Value : "<<graph_proptMain1[&gMainGraph].id<<endl;
cout<<"Sub G Value : "<<graph_proptsubG[&subG].id<<endl;
cout<<"Sub G1 Value : "<<graph_proptsubG1[&subG1].id<<endl;
cout<<"Map Value Main: "<<(map.value(&gMainGraph))<<endl;
cout<<"Map Value SubG: "<<(map.value(&subG))<<endl;
cout<<"Map Value SubG1b: "<<(map.value(&subG1))<<endl;

return a.exec();
}
mapGraphToProperty getMap(Graph &graph)
{
    mapGraphToProperty map;
    graphMapRecur(map,graph);
    return map;
}
void graphMapRecur(mapGraphToProperty &map, Graph &graph)
{
   Graph::children_iterator itrSubgraph, itrSubgraph_end;
   for (boost::tie(itrSubgraph, itrSubgraph_end) = (graph).children(); itrSubgraph != itrSubgraph_end; ++itrSubgraph)
    {
        graphMapRecur(map,(*itrSubgraph));
    }
     GraphProperties* gp = &(get_property(graph,graph_IDproperty));
     map.insert(&graph,gp);
     cout<<"Recurrr"<<endl;
}
```